# How to get iframe attribute by Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have this HTML code on my pages:

```
<iframe id="tubepress-video-object-1481217710" data-videoid="gCVXhS5Szbk" data-playerimplementation="youtube" data-videoprovidername="youtube" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="525" height="450" src="https:something..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The iframe's id changed everytimes the webpage reload. I can get the iframe's id by Javascript, but I don't know how to get the value of "**data-videoid**". 
Any boydy can help me please?

Comment: `iframeElement.dataset.videoid`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: var article = document.querySelector('#'+a); // My iframe id is a variable a
document.write(article.dataset.data-videoid); // "3"
alert(article.dataset.data-videoid);
Nothing happen!
Could you please give me an example?

Comment: I gave you a working example! Have you tried it, exactly as I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Use document.getElementById('tubepress-video-object-1481217710').getAttribute("data-videoid")

Comment: @Laxmi: getElementById('..') will not work..as id is changing every time the page reload.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the first or only IFRAME element on a page:

```
var frame = document.querySelector('iframe');
```

Then getting an attribute:

```
var val = frame.getAttribute('data-videoid');
```

Or getting a data- attribute:

```
var val = frame.dataset.videoid;
```

Comment: You should always include an explanation of what your code does so that future users who see this will know why this should work and what is going on.